# How to change the way the output is printed?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am entering text via a form and the text is being broken down into specific keywords within the sentence. Those keywords are associated with company names which are stored in a msql table. For example right now If I enter "need a plumber to get the pipe fixed'" I get the output b"[('WeHateSinksPlumbing',), ('FamilyPlumbers',)]\n" printed to my Django webpage. How would I clean up this output and just get the names of the companies separated by commas? I want the output just to be "WeHateSinksPlumbing, FamilyPlumbers". Let me know if you need to see any more code to help solve this issue.

Here is the method that is getting the company names from the db table

```
def match_tweet_for_website(self,weboutput):
            #this method uses the list impwords and matches the keywords from it
            #to the db and gets the company keywords for the keywords in the sentance
            #output= WebOutput.WebOutput(input("Enter Tweet "))
        # print(weboutput.impWords) 
            info = ', '.join(weboutput.impWords)
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor(buffered=True)
        # print(', '.join(weboutput.impWords))
            query= f"SELECT DISTINCT company_name FROM CompanyKeywords where keyword IN ({info})"
            self.cursor.execute(query,(info))
            result = self.cursor.fetchall()     
            unwanted="[(')]"
            for char in unwanted:
                result=[result.replace(char,"") for item in result]

            print(result)
```

code for the object

```
import DatabaseInteractor
import nltk

class WebOutput:

   #still need to add hashtag functionality 
  def __init__(self,text):
    self.text= text
    db = DatabaseInteractor.DatabaseInteractor()
    self.keywords= db.get_keywords()
    self.impWords = self.store_useful_words()
    #self.hashtag = input("Enter Hashtag")


  def store_useful_words(self):
    #this takes the tweet text and finds out which keywords are in that
    #text and stores it in a list 
    tweetWords = []
    for word in self.text.split():
      if word in self.keywords:
        tweetWords.append("'"+word+"'")
    return tweetWords
```

HTML code for the form

```
 <container >  
          <form action="/searchoutput/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            Input Text:
            <input type="text" name="param" required> <br><br>
            {{data_external}}<br><br>
            {{data}}
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Check tweet">

            </form>
        </container>
```

views.py method

```
def searchoutput(request):
  inp = request.POST.get('param')
  out= run([sys.executable,'//Users//yaminhimani//Desktop//tweetybird//WebOutputTest.py',inp],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
  print(out)
  return render(request,'search.html',{'data': out.stdout})
```

Comment: I know this seems pretty obvious but have you tried using the `split()` function but with commas passed in as a parameter. `split(',')`

Comment: Where would I use the split in my code?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't thoroughly read through your problem. The answer you want is probably the answer down below

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop for that! here is an example:

```
# Python3 code example
# Remove special unwanted characters
# Using replace()

# Initializing original string
original = "%T;h@is$ t:est ^S~te&ch*ie&s"

# Printing original string
print ("Original String: " + original)

# Initializing unwanted string
unwanted = "!@#$;:!*%)(&^~"

# Run for loop with each character of string and remove unwanted characters
for char in unwanted:
 original = original.replace(char,"")
# Printing final string
print("Final Output: " + original)
```

Hope That Helps! if you have any question just ask ;)
Note: this is just demo.

Comment: How would I do this in my case? I am getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'. Since I am trying to take unwanted characters out of a list. I will add the code I added to the question.

Comment: Hey Yamin, just add `str(your_list)`, like you can do `original = str(your_list)` and it should work perfectly! if any question ask me. ;)